# How to move from npm to yarn in my laravel, vue/cli apps?

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, yarnpkg

I want to move from npm to yarn in my laravel, vue/cli apps and viewing / reading some tutorials 
I see yarn.lock file mentioned ion the root of the app.
But running command for new laravel app creation:
laravel new ya_prj
I do not any yarn.lock or yarn.* files in newly created project
I have yarn installed :

```
$ yarn --version                  
0.32
```

Did I miss some options?

Also how can I to replace npw with yarn for my laravel 5.7-6, vue/cli 4 apps locally and on live server?

Comment: You should just be able to run `yarn` and it will create the lock file for you.

Comment: looks like I had some other yarn
I installed valid with command : sudo npm install -g yarn and after that I have yarn.lock in root of my app

Comment: What have I to do migrate from package.json to  yarn.lock ? Any scripts, manually ?\

Comment: Yarn still uses the `package.json`. For the most part Yarn is just a wrapper for `npm`. So, to answer your question, you don't have to do anything. Have you tried just running `yarn`?

Comment: Yes, with running yarn command file yarn.lock was generated. I suppose I DO NOT have to edit manually(habit from npm) by runniong console commands yarn add ... and yarn remove ?

Comment: No you won't have to edit it manually. You shouldn't need to edit package.json manually when using npm though either.

Comment: But seems I still need package.json in the project ? I tried to remove it and got errors runnung yarn install ...

Comment: Yes, you will still need to have the package.json file. This is how npm/yarn knows what packages your project needs so don't delete it.